# AjaxFileUpload has randomly stopped firing OnUploadComplete event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My AjaxFileUpload control has randomly stopped working in the last few weeks.

I am getting this chrome console error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cannotDeserializeInvalidJson' of undefined" - whenever I click the control's upload button. I'm not sure if this error is to do with the control not working, but the control's OnUploadCompled method is not being called.

Am totally pulling my hair out over this, cannot figure out what is going wrong as I have not made any significant changes between it working and not.

Any help would obviously be greatly appreciated!

Relevant code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"  style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px;">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgAsset"  runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnURl" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnShowimages" text="Show Images" CssClass="gallery-link" OnClientClick="showGallery(); return false;" runat="server" Style="position: center; bottom: 5px;" />
                    <cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxUpload" runat="server" OnClientUploadStart="clientUpload()" OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload_UploadComplete" Width="280px" style="min-width:200px; visibility:hidden; display:none;" MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnShowUpload" OnClientClick="showUploader();return false;" runat="server" Text="Add images" CssClass="btn btn-success" Style="position: center; bottom: 5px;" />


                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="saveMaintenanceForm" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-success" Style="position: center; bottom: 5px;" />
                    <label></label>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelFault" OnClick="btnCancel_Click1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Style="position: center; bottom: 5px;" CausesValidation="false" />
                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What version of Ajax Control Toolkit do you use?

Comment: @MikhailTymchuk Latest, 15.4 I believe.

Comment: Could you show error location you see in console? Any environment info also would be helpful.

Comment: (see my newer question) I found out that the cause was due to setting the parent user controls visible property initially to false, and then changing that dynamically.